# Picking the "spread" from the points on a line

Tags: algorithm, big-o, distance

I'm facing an algorithmic problem described as follows: Given a line from 0 to N (really big N), a list of X points on said line, and a number Z (0<=Z<=X) pick Z points from X to maximize the distance between two closest points. The brute-force solution in O(n^2) doesn't seem that difficult but I'm looking for something more sophisticated that can be done in O(n log n) time. Any clues, solutions, advice is very appreciated.

Edit: Answering the question in the first post-it is the minimal distance (between the two closest points) that has to be maximized.

Comment: Which quantity do you need to maximize exactly ? The minimal distance, the sum of the distance, the sum of the squared distances ?

Comment: n is the size of input in the "big Oh" notation

Comment: Well I'd assume the amount of calculations needed would be based both on X and Z but, for any given X and Z, they differ by a constant, so it makes no difference in the "O" notation, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Can you extend the question with a sketch of the brute force solution you mentioned?

Comment: Well, more or less I imagined the brute force solution to be - make the list of all the distances between the neighboring elements, pick the ones above the median adjusted for the Z/X ratio.

Comment: That's a bit too simple. imagine this ...--1---------2--3---------4--...  distance (1,2) and (3,4) are big, but you don't want to pick all 4 nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy approach is O(XlogN).

First, sort the points.

Next observe that if you already know the minimum distance (call it d) between the points, it's O(X) to see if there's a way of picking Z points all of which are at least distance d apart: take the left-most element, then the next that's at least distance d away, then the next that's at least distance d away from that, and so on. If by the time you've got to the end of the array you have at least Z points, then you have a solution, and if you don't, there is no solution.

Now, you can use a binary search on [0, N] to find the largest d with a solution.

The sort is O(XlogX), the binary search takes O(logN) trials, and each is O(X). Overall, that's O(XlogX + XlogN), but since N >= X that simplifies to O(XlogN).

Comment: Nice solution ! Can this be salvaged if N is infinite ? One solution is to pre-compute all point to point distances and do the binary search on this set but this adds an O(X^2) complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it was very helpful and I finally feel like I'll make some progress on this. Can you please confirm that I understood you correctly? 1. I sort the points (or they can be already sorted) 2. I make a binary search in N to find the possible minimum distance 3. Check it with X 4. Go back to point 3 with my binary search based on the result of the previous step. So assuming that I got the above correctly the only problem is - when should I stop the search as theoretically I can halve the search distance ad infinitum, so I am probably missing something.